# Dog Year Birthdate Query

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mySQL:

```
---Dogs---
id        int
birthdate date
```

On average, a dog adds 7 years to its life, every year.
Basically I would like to know if today is the dog's actual birthday or if it's their dog birthday. It's approximately 52 days between each dog birthday. I can't figure out how to write this query at all.

I would like rows returned that would look like this:

```
|-----------------|
| id | birthdate  |
|-----------------|
| 40 | 2003-12-08 |
| 59 | 2007-12-08 |
| 87 | 2005-06-07 | <- 
| 33 | 2009-11-05 | <- Not sure if these would be accurate but want them to
|    |            |    return if today worked out being their 'dog birthday'
```

Also, their actual birthdate is much more important to me. I don't want to rely on a date_diff calculation. Where birthdate = today OR birthdate = calculated date.

I think I peiced it together. I did this and it seems to be working the way I want:

```
select distinct(d.id) from Dogs d
where MONTH( CURDATE( ) ) = MONTH( d.birthdate  )
AND DAYOFMONTH( CURDATE( ) ) = DAYOFMONTH( d.birthdate )
or
datediff (curdate(), d.birthdate) % 52 = 0
```

Comment: seach for "modulo operator mysql" and see if that gives you anything to start with.  Otherwise you could build a subquery that has all the dog birthdays by date arithmetic, and see if whatever day you're interested in is in that table.  What do you want your query to do, something like show all the dogs who's dog birthday is today?  Give an example of the rows you would like returned, showing what columns are in each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use modulus :-

```
select id
from Dogs
where datediff (curdate(), birthday) %52 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly the same calculation as if it was a human - then multiply by 7.

Comment: That would mean a dog would go straight from age 7 to 14 without any intermediate birthdays wouldn't it?